# Retrofit + gson ошибка разбора JSON

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, gson

Имеются классы

```
data class Article(
    val content: String?,

    val publishedAt: String?,

    val author: String?,

    val urlToImage: String?,

    val title: String?,

    val source: Source?,

    val description: String?,

    val url: String?
)

data class Result (
        val articles: List<Article>?,

        val totalResults: Int?,

        val status: String?

)
data class Source(
        var id : Int?,

        var name : String?
)
```

Имеется интерфейс

```
interface ApiService{
    @GET("top-headlines")
    fun getTopHeadlines(@Query("sources") sources: String,
                        @Query("apiKey") apiKey: String): Single<Result>

//    fun getTopHeadlines(@Query("sources") sources : String, @Query("apiKey") apiKey : String): Call<Cities>




    companion object Factory {

        fun create(): ApiService {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(APIUrl.baseUrl)
                    .build()

            return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        }
    }

}
```

Пытаюсь получить данные c api

```
val apiService = ApiService.create()


        apiService.getTopHeadlines("techcrunch", APIUrl.newsApi)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        {
                            result -> Log.d("Ответ", result.totalResults.toString())
//
                        },
                        {
                            throwable: Throwable? -> Log.d("Ошибка",throwable.toString())

                        }
                )
```

Кидает ошибку:

```
D/Ошибка: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "techcrunch"
```

Как исправить?

JSON:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 10,
    "articles": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
            "author": "Jon Russell",
            "title": "Golden Gate Ventures closes new $100M fund for Southeast Asia",
            "description": "Singapore’s Golden Gate Ventures has announced the close of its newest (and third) fund for Southeast Asia at a total of $100 million. The first hit a first close in the summer, as TechCrunch reported at the time, and now it has reached full capacity. Seven-y…",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2018/09/13/golden-gate-ventures-closes-new-100m-fund-for-southeast-asia/",
            "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/golden-gate-ventures.png?w=749",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-14T01:21:29Z",
            "content": "Singapore’s Golden Gate Ventures has announced the close of its newest (and third) fund for Southeast Asia at a total of $100 million. The first hit a first close in the summer, as TechCrunch reported at the time, and now it has reached full capacity. Seven-y… [+2670 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
            "author": "Connie Loizos",
            "title": "A Tesla investor says he was recently questioned by U.S. regulators about that infamous \"funding secured\" tweet",
            "description": "Last week, on stage at TechCrunch Disrupt, regulator Jina Choi, who heads the SEC’s wide-reaching San Francisco unit, declined to confirm or deny that the SEC is investigating Tesla CEO Elon Musk for possible fraud. Said Choi, “I can’t tell you about any part…",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2018/09/13/a-tesla-investor-says-he-was-recently-questioned-by-u-s-regulators-about-that-infamous-funding-secured-tweet/",
            "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/GettyImages-974773044.jpg?w=600",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-13T23:39:31Z",
            "content": "Last week, on stage at TechCrunch Disrupt, regulator Jina Choi, who heads the SEC’s wide-reaching San Francisco unit, declined to confirm or deny that the SEC is investigating Tesla CEO Elon Musk for possible fraud. Said Choi, “I can’t tell you about any part… [+2700 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
            "author": "Lucas Matney",
            "title": "Nintendo finally announces some new games for the Switch",
            "description": "Nintendo is at last (at last!) bringing some new content to the Switch! Yes! In a Nintendo Direct, the company let fly a number of games and a couple of original titles. The biggest Nintendo-produced titles we had glimpses of are a new Animal Crossing in deve…",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2018/09/13/nintendo-finally-announces-some-more-new-games-for-the-switch/",
            "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Screen-Shot-2018-09-13-at-4.47.25-PM.png?w=696",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-13T23:38:07Z",
            "content": "Nintendo is at last (at last!) bringing some new content to the Switch! Yes! In a Nintendo Direct, the company let fly a number of games and a couple of original titles. The biggest Nintendo-produced titles we had glimpses of are a new Animal Crossing in deve… [+1682 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
            "author": "Devin Coldewey",
            "title": "Nintendo's NES Switch controllers activate the nostalgia centers (and wallets) of retro gamers",
            "description": "The news that Nintendo would be adding NES games to the Switch as part of its paid online service had a mixed reception, but the company has made up for this controversial decision by releasing wireless NES controllers to play those games with. At $60 they’re…",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2018/09/13/nintendos-nes-switch-controllers-activate-the-nostalgia-centers-and-wallets-of-retro-gamers/",
            "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/nintendo_controllers.jpg?w=676",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-13T23:18:09Z",
            "content": "The news that Nintendo would be adding NES games to the Switch as part of its paid online service had a mixed reception, but the company has made up for this controversial decision by releasing wireless NES controllers to play those games with. At $60 they’re… [+1742 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
            "author": "Brian Heater",
            "title": "The iPhone XR is the one to get",
            "description": "The iPhone XR arrived like an afterthought. No surprise, really. Apple’s always been one to lead with its best foot forward — the latest, greatest and, quite literally, the largest. Projecting the life on the bleeding edge is a cornerstone of the company’s im…",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2018/09/13/the-iphone-xr-is-the-one-to-get/",
            "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/IMG_32041.jpg?w=600",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-13T22:53:40Z",
            "content": "The iPhone XR arrived like an afterthought. No surprise, really. Apple’s always been one to lead with its best foot forward — the latest, greatest and, quite literally, the largest. Projecting the life on the bleeding edge is a cornerstone of the company’s im… [+3607 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
            "author": "Kate Clark",
            "title": "Former Uber exec alleges ex-PR chief 'destroyed his reputation'",
            "description": "A nasty legal battle is set to play out between two former Uber executives. Eric Alexander, the ride-hailing company’s former president of business in Asia-Pacific, has filed suit against former Uber PR chief Rachel Whetstone . Alexander blames Whetstone for …",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2018/09/13/former-uber-exec-alleges-ex-pr-chief-destroyed-his-reputation/",
            "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/gettyimages-147563225.jpg?w=710",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-13T22:00:19Z",
            "content": "A nasty legal battle is set to play out between two former Uber executives. Eric Alexander, the ride-hailing company’s former president of business in Asia-Pacific, has filed suit against former Uber PR chief Rachel Whetstone. Alexander blames Whetstone for h… [+3070 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
            "author": "Megan Rose Dickey",
            "title": "Twitch hires head of diversity and inclusion",
            "description": "Twitch, the Amazon-owned streaming platform, has brought on its first head of diversity and inclusion, as well as a new chief financial officer and chief human resources officer. Katrina Jones, who will start next month as Twitch’s head of diversity and inclu…",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2018/09/13/twitch-hires-head-of-diversity-and-inclusion/",
            "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/gettyimages-488852552.jpeg?w=600",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-13T21:00:30Z",
            "content": "Twitch, the Amazon-owned streaming platform, has brought on its first head of diversity and inclusion, as well as a new chief financial officer and chief human resources officer. Katrina Jones, who will start next month as Twitch’s head of diversity and inclu… [+788 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
            "author": "Danny Crichton",
            "title": "The second blockchain bubble is now complete - what’s next?",
            "description": "The last few months haven’t been easy for crypto investors. Following the dizzying highs of crypto trading late last year, which saw Bitcoin reach a peak of $19,276 and a market cap of $323 billion and Ether reach $1,152 with a market cap of more than $112 bi…",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2018/09/13/the-second-blockchain-bubble-is-now-complete-whats-next/",
            "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/GettyImages-809812328.jpg?w=611",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-13T20:57:57Z",
            "content": "The last few months haven’t been easy for crypto investors. Following the dizzying highs of crypto trading late last year, which saw Bitcoin reach a peak of $19,276 and a market cap of $323 billion and Ether reach $1,152 with a market cap of more than $112 bi… [+6710 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
            "author": "Jose Deustua",
            "title": "The funding mirage: How to secure international investment from emerging markets",
            "description": "Looking for funding as a startup in Latin America is a lot like looking for a watering hole in the middle of the desert. You know it’s out there, but finding it in time is a life or death situation.",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2018/09/13/the-funding-mirage-how-to-secure-international-investment-from-emerging-markets/",
            "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/mirage.jpg?w=602",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-13T20:00:50Z",
            "content": "Looking for funding as a startup in Latin America is a lot like looking for a watering hole in the middle of the desert. You know it’s out there, but finding it in time is a life or death situation. Granted, venture capital investment in the region is at an a… [+6948 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
            "author": "John Biggs",
            "title": "It's the end of crypto as we know it and I feel fine",
            "description": "Watching the current price madness is scary. Bitcoin is falling and rising in $500 increments with regularity and Ethereum and its attendant ICOs are in a seeming freefall with a few “dead cat bounces” to keep things lively. What this signals is not that cryp…",
            "url": "https://techcrunch.com/2018/09/13/its-the-end-of-crypto-as-we-know-it-and-i-feel-fine/",
            "urlToImage": "https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/giphy-1.gif?w=480",
            "publishedAt": "2018-09-13T19:55:06Z",
            "content": "Watching the current price madness is scary. Bitcoin is falling and rising in $500 increments with regularity and Ethereum and its attendant ICOs are in a seeming freefall with a few “dead cat bounces” to keep things lively. What this signals is not that cryp… [+5408 chars]"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может потому что в классе

```
data class Source(
        var id : Int?,

        var name : String?
)
```

поле `id` типа `int`, а json-ответе в `id` содержится строка?

```
"source": {
                "id": "techcrunch",
                "name": "TechCrunch"
            },
```

И об этом прямо и говорится в тексте ошибки, что не может сроку `'techcrunch'` привести к числу.

Comment: Спасибо, проморгал