# Вложеный масив в Retrofit

Tags: java, json, kotlin, retrofit, coroutine

Не часто работал с `Retrofit`-м, поэтому еще плохо знаю все. Недавно добавил в бекенд пагинацию и следовательно в клиентов изменился `json` ответ.

```
         { 
         "content":[  
                  {  
                     "id":1,
                     "date":1549549535,
                     "recipeTitle":"testMP"
                  }
               ],
               "last":true,
               "totalElements":4,
               "totalPages":1,
               "sort":[  
                  {  
                     "direction":"DESC",
                     "property":"id",
                     "ignoreCase":false,
                     "nullHandling":"NATIVE",
                     "ascending":false,
                     "descending":true
                  }
               ],
               "first":true,
               "numberOfElements":4,
               "size":100,
               "number":0
            }
```

Следовательно пытаюсь получить содержимое `сontent`.
Интерфейс с запросами:

```
interface ReportService {
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke() : ReportService{
            val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                            HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            }).build()

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("http://*****")
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(httpClient)
                        .build()
            return retrofit.create(ReportService::class.java)
        }
    }

    @GET("reports")
    fun getReports(@Query("page") page : Int) : Deferred<List<Report>>

    @GET("reports/{id}")
    fun getReport(@Path("id") id : Long) : Deferred<Report>
}
```

Функция загрузки результата в репозитории:

```
fun getReportsList() : List<Report>? {
        var reportList : List<Report> = listOf()
        try {
            runBlocking {
                async {
                    val request : List<Report> = ReportService.invoke().getReports(0).await()
                    reportList = request
                }.await()
            }
        }catch (e : Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return reportList
    }
```

Как взять вложеный массив `content`?Нужно писать свою реализацию `TypeAdapter<>` для `gson`-а?

Comment: `Report` это и есть то, что внути `content`?

Comment: Вот тут можете идеи почерпнуть для написания правильного data class-а. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881162/retrofit-gson-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-json

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, да, это масив report-ов